# Xcode 5 DSYM file not found in instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, debug-symbols, dsym

I am trying to use instruments to profile my code, in XCode 5, but it is not finding my dsym file, when I attempt to set the dsym file manually using file->symbols in instruments the library parent directory under which the dsym file is created is not visible what the heck do I need to do to make this library visible in the file selector so that it can properly find the dsym file?

And yes, I know I can copy the file external to that directory and choose it from there, but that is not a viable solution as I would have to do this after every rebuild.  WHy the heck would Apple set this up in this way in the first place..  Annoying.